# Translate React App using data stored in database

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I use an API soccer in my laravel App with React who provide a JSON data file but with default English language like this:

```
https://apiv3.apifootball.com/?action=get_countries&APIkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The output is :

```
enter [
   { 
   "country_id": "44",
   "country_name": "England",
   "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/44_england.png"
   },
   {
   "country_id": "6",
   "country_name": "Spain",
   "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/6_spain.png"
   },
   {
  "country_id": "3",
  "country_name": "France",
  "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/3_france.png"
  },
  {
  "country_id": "4",
  "country_name": "Germany",
  "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/4_germany.png"
  },
  {
  "country_id": "5",
  "country_name": "Italy",
  "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/5_italy.png"
  },
  ....
  ]
```

The React web application in multilingual so I need to make translation of some specific fields in the joson file. Firstly I tried using a translation API but all of them are not free and need to pay to get an API key. Then I tried another way is to make translation from data stored already in database.

The idea is to make for example the translation to french language :

```
 [
  {
   "country_id": "44",
   "country_name": "Angleterre",
   "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/44_england.png"
  },
 .....
```

So I will have already `England` stored and translated to `Angleterre` in DB.

I'm very beginner with React so I need some help to store and extract translation data from DB, really I don't know yet how to do it?

Comment: @Krampus Yes I see about react-i18next and I gonna use it to make a multi multilanguage website but the translation of json file is different because it will be updated all time on database, that mean for every new team for example I should add it in database too not making a direct translation..!